# Schema-validation: missing table when upgrading to spring-boot-3 (Hibernate 6 )

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-6.x

**Background:**

I have upgraded my spring boot project from '2.5.12' to '3.0.0'.

As part of the upgrade hibernate was also updated to 6.1.5.

All the java entities are now using jakarta.persistence instead of javax.persistence
[as required](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0)

**The issue:**

When the application starts an error is thrown

```
Schema-validation: missing table ...
```

The error is thrown from org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator

The function validateTable meant to validate that the entities match the DB tables.

```
    @Override
protected void validateTables(
        Metadata metadata,
        DatabaseInformation databaseInformation,
        ExecutionOptions options,
        ContributableMatcher contributableInclusionFilter,
        Dialect dialect, Namespace namespace) {

    final NameSpaceTablesInformation tables = databaseInformation.getTablesInformation( namespace );
    for ( Table table : namespace.getTables() ) {
        if ( options.getSchemaFilter().includeTable( table )
                && table.isPhysicalTable()
                && contributableInclusionFilter.matches( table ) ) {
            validateTable(
                    table,
                    tables.getTableInformation( table ),
                    metadata,
                    options,
                    dialect
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional info:**

1. The DB tables exist, i can log in and see them.
2. The `databaseInformation.getTablesInformation( namespace );` returns empty results.
3. The `namespace.getTables()` shows all the tables correctly.
4. Hibernate generated classes are created O.K as part of the build (so annotations seem to be working).
5. Using MySQLDialect
6. Entities didn't change beside using jakarta.persistence
7. I don't get any "Connection refused " so connection to the DB is created.

**The question:**

Any idea what might be the cause?

Is there an issue with the model or reading schema data from the DB?

Might this be an issue of some dependency incompatibility?

Comment: Since you must be debugging, I think you misinterpreted the code. The NameSpaceTablesInformation is the part where it looks at the DB metadata to find what is in your schema - if tables is empty, it didn't find any tables in your schema. First things are the simple ones - check your connection properties and that it went to the db/schema you thought it should where your tables are. Relying on a 'javax.persistence' property when you've switched to Jakarta for instance. Otherwise, check what that line would have returned and what is different with the 'namespace' provided before the upgrade

Comment: Thanks, there is only one DB and one schema, so once the connection is created, there isn't really anywhere else to connect beside the correct ones. The namespace provided to the getTablesInformation has null for Catalog and null for Schema which means all is acceptable